# General Input Output Error while using Google Drive

Tags: libreoffice, google-drive

I just upgraded to LibrOffice 5.1.3. I want to save my files to Google Drive and when I added my Google Drive account it didn't gave any error whatsoever. I entered my email ID in username and my password in password in Google Drive and I don't have 2 factor authentication.

Anyway when I try to save a file to Remote Server or Open Remote Files I get this General Input Out Error. 
Saving files on my HDD is working without any problem, its just a problem with Remote servers. I can't really understand what the problem is. Any solutions would be welcome.

Comment: This is a bug that hasn't been solved in 5.2.1.2 yet.

Comment: It does work. But only with installation from Deb file or external source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install LibreOffice from their official site and Online storage facility will work. This is not working for the repository installs and upgrades. Installation through their site i.e. downloading and installing from deb, rpm or the preferable format.